# How to define Biharmonic operator for second order sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, operator-theory, elliptic-pde

I am studying an article [Link of Article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC0QFjACahUKEwjwib--xYPIAhVBEywKHfX-CN4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uam.es%2Fpersonal_pdi%2Fciencias%2Fmapperez%2Fultimos_trabajos%2FPerezPrimoRevised.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEWUiwjrczoQQhswakkxluVyOuXHQ&sig2=qBb35mgMKVMfdd2-rSjHxA&bvm=bv.103073922,d.bGg). There author assumes that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, $ N>4 $ . Some where in the paper we have

$$ \Delta^2 (\cdot) - \frac{\lambda}{|x|^4} (\cdot) : W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) \to W_0^{-2,2}(\Omega) $$ (This operator is in the Page 4-th of article)

and aslo we have

$$ \Delta^2 (\cdot) : W^{2,2}(\Omega) \to W^{-2,2}(\Omega) $$

(This operator is at the begining of the Page 11-th of article)

I do not have any problem with the singular term, my question is this that I can not understand how does these linear operators has defined? Because biharmonic operator is fourth order but how can we define biharmonic operator for functions of second order sobolev spaces?

Also Author has said that the first one is coercive and the second one is a continuous operator.

Can some one help me? So thanks

Comment: Note that the target (or range, or codomain, or whatever) of the operator is $W^{-2,2}$, which is a Sobolev space of *negative* order. In general an $m$-th order differential operator will decrease the order of the Sobolev space by $m$.